# how can I run an external program In C?

Tags: c, winapi

How can I run an external program in C? For example application programs like a `browser`, `word`, `Notepad`, etc. Also how can I set a certain size of the window of the external application program? For example a window size of `300 X 300` pixels.

Comment: Each thread should be a single question.  You should create a new thread for the second question (though a quick search will find you answers for both of them).

Answer (score 14):

The standard way is `system` -- works pretty much anywhere, but gives you no control over how the child process runs.

In ascending order of control (and complexity), Windows provides: [`WinExec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687393.aspx), [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153.aspx), [`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762154.aspx), and [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx). With CreateProcess you pass a [`STARTUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331.aspx) or [`STARTUPINFOEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686329.aspx) structure. Either way, you can specify the starting position and/or size for the child window (though the child process can and may move/resize its window before it's even visible).

You might also want to consider [`Boost Process`](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/), which isn't accepted as an official part of Boost, but provides a bit more control than `system`, while remaining reasonably portable to a fair number of the most widely used systems (including both Windows and anything reasonably POSIX-like, such as Linux or OS X).

Comment: The problem with `system` is that it opens the console (in Windows anyway). Is there any way to get rid of that?

Comment: I think the list of alternatives I've given remains reasonably accurate. If you need to capture output from the child's `stdout` or feed input to its `stdin`, you might also consider `popen`. I've also added a pointer to Boost.Process, which you might find useful (but note that despite the name, it's not officially a released part of Boost).

Answer (score 2):

You run and external program using [system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_%28C_standard_library%29) from the C standard library or the Win32 [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

To resize a the main window of an application you create. First start the process with CreateWindow. Then use [EnumThreadWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633495%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the handle from CreateProcess to find the main window of that process. Finally, you can call [MoveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with that handle to set the size and position.

Answer (score 2):

you can use system function for this purpose like,

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("your-program-name");

    return 0;
}
```

This will be executed in command prompt.

But if you want to use winapi the best way is to use CreateProcess() function,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To run an external program, the most straighforward method is with [`system`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html). There are other options (use search).

To set the window size, you must interact with your window manager and ask it to do that. I don't know if that is possible for you (Windows has a ["start"](http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm) command that you may find helpful, if you use that OS).

Answer (score 0):

You could also check [**_popen**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (*stdio.h*) for console applications (only).

To create a Windows application that redirects input and output, see [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499.aspx) in the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Never use system() on Windows
(forbidden)
Use the Shell apis